# Steps of compilation

Tags: c, gcc, build, linker

I am trying to compile simple Hello World C program in a sequential manner. First creating the preprocessed file, then creating the assembly file, then creating the object file and finally invoking the linker to create the ELF.

The problem is I am not able to execute the ELF being created.

I have tried following steps

```
gcc -E hello.c 1>hello.i

gcc -S hello.i

gcc -c hello.s

ld -o hello hello.o -lc
```

At this step I got a warning saying

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400260
```

But an executable with the name hello is created.

When I try to execute the output using

```
./hello
```

I am getting the error

```
bash: ./hello: No such file or directory
```

//hello.c contains following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("\tHello World \n");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you do all these steps when building? Why not plain `gcc hello.c -o hello`?

Comment: As for the linker problem, use the `gcc` front-end program to link as well, as it will add the startup code needed to make your executable program.

Comment: `main` is not the real entrypoint of the program. You probably need to link with some `crt0.o` file which contains the `_start` symbol.... or let `gcc` work

Comment: Run `gcc -v -o hello hello.c` to see what the compiler actually does to invoke the loader.  It provides a file such as `crt0.o` which provides the `_start` entry point that sets up the environment for calling `main()` and cleaning up when it returns.  It does a whole lot more, too; it will probably horrify you.

Comment: GCC 9.1.0 on a Mac run as `gcc -v -o hello hello71.c` has a `collect2` phase followed by `ld` run with the command line: `/usr/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o hello71 -L/opt/gcc/v9.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/9.1.0 -L/opt/gcc/v9.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/9.1.0/../../.. /var/folders/vn/wv38v30s4hz3yvbkdtbn049c0000gn/T//cco4GE8M.o -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v`.  The `/var/folders/…` location is where the object file got put — it's the value of `$TMPDIR`.

Comment: In your last step you probably need something like `ld -o hello /lib/crt0.o hello.o -lc`.  (But `crt0.o` is the filename I remember from back in my PDP-11 days.  It's probably different, and more complicated, by now.)

Comment: Could someone (with more rep than me) remove the [compiler-construction] tag from this question? It doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you link your object files (however they are produced) with gcc, not ld.

gcc will call ld with the appropriate options, since it knows more about the source code and will create whatever is necessary for the assumptions that ld makes.